# Drupal form validation- node reference fields match in quantity

Tags: forms, drupal

I have 2 separate node reference fields for a particular content type. I would like to ensure that both fields have an equal number of nodes specified. Any help appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 6.x...

You will have to attach a custom validation handler to your form via hook_form_alter, for example:

```
function my_module_form_alter (&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "my_form_to_modify")
    $form['#validate'][] = "my_module_form_validate_handler";
}

function my_module_form_validate_handler ($form, &$form_state) {
  if (sizeof($form_state['values']['field_my_node_ref_1']) != sizeof($form_state['values']['field_my_node_ref_2'])) {
    form_set_error("field_my_node_ref_1","You have to supply equal number of nodes...");
  }
}
```